# Jquery bug dblclick/click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I've been experimenting with jquery and have come upon a problem. http://javascript.nicklewers.co.uk/nav/
On the 'Android' tab I've set it so that if you click once, the sub menu will appear, however when doubleclicking, the main content will appear.

Now the problem is: a double click involves two single clicks which involves the sub menu opening and closing very quickly and this looks bad. How do I prevent this?

Comment: please post the code that you think is not working http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/something-on-my-web-site-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it

Comment: Just a little pointer - double click is completely _non-standard behaviour_ in web browsers. You should probably implement it differently instead of relying on events that people don't know how to use.

Comment: you can try to use `.mouseenter()` to load the submenu and use `.click()` on the topmenu. Imho better usability.

Comment: Christian-yes I know this is an abnormal feature,but I'm new to jQuery and love exploring/experimenting with its features!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this (using a timer to know if single click or double):

```
alreadyclicked=false;
$('#android').bind('click',function(){
    var el=$(this);
    if (alreadyclicked)
    {
        alreadyclicked=false; // reset
        clearTimeout(alreadyclickedTimeout); // prevent this from happening
        // do what needs to happen on double click. 
    }
    else
    {
        alreadyclicked=true;
        alreadyclickedTimeout=setTimeout(function(){
            alreadyclicked=false; // reset when it happens
            // do what needs to happen on single click. 
            // use el instead of $(this) because $(this) is 
            // no longer the element
        },300); // <-- dblclick tolerance here
    }
    return false;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try a delay before showing/hiding the submenu.  With JS this can be done using the `setTimeout()` function.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#android').dblclick(function(){
    $('.content, #subnav').toggle();
});
```

why do you toggle both the content and the submenu? Removing it is not going to solve the problem, but I think it should not be there.